# Add a line break after 4 words in a String in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to make Customer Receipts using PrintDocuments Control and now I want to display a footer on Customer Receipts. The footer Text stored in a string type variable:
`String Footertex="ABC DEF GHIJK LMNOP QRSTUVWXYZ AAA BBBBBBB ABCD";`
but I use a thermal printer for customer receipts and only the following text is printed in the footer:

```
ABC DEF GHIJK LMNOP
```

Now I want it automatically break the line and the have the remaining text displayed on the next line, like so:

```
ABC DEF GHIJK LMNOP
QRSTUVWXYZ AAA 
BBBBBBB ABCD
```

I simply want that if the text has a number of characters greater than 19 it breaks the line and prints the remaining text in the next line.
Thanks in advance.

```
string item = (_List[i].Qty + " x " + _List[i].Name);
int nInterval1 = 18;
string res1 = String.Concat(item.Select((c, j) => i > 0 && (i % nInterval1) == 0 ? c.ToString() + Environment.NewLine : c.ToString()));
```

I've tried the above code, but it breaks the string after 18 characters, but in some cases, it doesn't make sense to break the line after 18 characters, because it breaks any word. I want to break the line after a complete word.

Comment: if thermal prnter can print html documents, you should be able to use html template with wrapping features.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using following code (with my comments):

```
var item = "Hide Copy Code QRSTUVWXYZ AAA BBBBBBB ABCD";
const int interval = 18;
var words = item.Split();
var result = "";
var symbolsInCurrentLine = 0;
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (word.Length + symbolsInCurrentLine > interval)  // after adding word line will be longer than required
    {
        result += "\n";
        symbolsInCurrentLine = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (symbolsInCurrentLine > 0)  // add space after previous word if needed
        {
            result += " ";
            symbolsInCurrentLine++;
        }
        result += word;  // append word
        symbolsInCurrentLine += word.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your technique is work when i display the value of result in a message box  it fork fine. it break the line. but Now i want to Print the braked  line in a Customer recipt using Print Document just like this  " graphics.DrawString(result, myfont, Brushes.Black, 10, startY = startY + 20); " but it just display first 18 Words it ignor the words that come after 18 words please help me how can i solve it.

Comment: Do you have space to print other words?

Comment: Cool! Please accept this answer if it was helpful :)